# Disable past dates of 2 datepickers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 datepickers which go from date to date. I'm able to disable past dates of the first datepicker. But it doesn't work for the second one. I've watched the behaviour of the second. When I click on the second first, past dates are well disabled. But, when I click on the first one and then go to the second, it doesn't work anymore.

```
$("#date1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate:0, 
    onSelect: daysNumber,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
         var dParts = selectedDate.split('-');
         var days = new Date(dParts[2] + '/' +
                    dParts[1] + '/' +
                    (+dParts[0] + 30)
               );

    $( "#date2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", days);
    }
});

var plusOne = $('#date2').datepicker('getDate')+1;

$("#date2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: daysNumber,  
    minDate:plusOne,
});
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to fetch a `Date` object value for your first date picker, rather than trying to parse the `selectedDate` string.

In that case you can use `.getTime()` to get the epoch, and then you just add the number of milliseconds in one day. Then you create a `new Date` from the epoch, and use that to set the minDate.

```
$("#date1").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  minDate: 0,
  onSelect: daysNumber,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#date2").datepicker("option", "minDate", plusOne());
  }
});

var plusOne = function() {
  var d1 = $('#date1').datepicker('getDate');
  var msInDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours * mins * secs * ms
  if (!d1) return 0;
  else return new Date(d1.getTime() + msInDay);
}

$("#date2").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  onSelect: daysNumber,
  minDate: plusOne(),
});
```